# While and JQuery Dialog

Tags: php, jquery

I have this code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if($i++%2==0){
       $color="#FFFFFF";
    }else{
       $color="#CCCCCC";
    }

    ?>

    <tr bgcolor='<?php echo $color; ?>' onmouseover="this.style.background='#ABFB04';" onmouseout="this.style.background='<?php echo $color; ?>';">
    <?php

echo "<td class=tablelist>";

echo $row["ICAO"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Name"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["WeightEmpty"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["WeightFull"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["CargoFull"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Range"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Price"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["FirstClassSeats"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["BusinessClassSeats"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["EconomyClassSeats"]. '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo "<img id='editaircraft' src='./images/info.png'></td></tr>"; 

?>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#editaircraftdialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 425
        });

        $( "#editaircraft" ).click(function() {
            $( "#editaircraftdialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    }); 
</script>

<div id="editaircraftdialog" title="Edit Aircraft">
    <p>Hello World!!</p>
</div>

<?php
}

echo "</table>";
$pagination->render();
?>
```

It´s the content for the lines of a PHP table. I want when I click on the image info.png in any of the lines of the table It shows the JQuery dialog "editaircraftdialog".

With this code. I only see the dialog when I click in the image of the firts line. If I click on the second or other that isn´t line 1 It don´t show the dialog.

Comment: You are outputting multiple elements on the page with the same ID attribute (editaircraft).  You should change these to use unique IDs or CSS classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be duplicate HTML element IDs, like vimalnath said ID's are always unique. If you have two rows (or more) you would end up with two  elements with the same ID hence the jQuery selector used would pick up the first element only.

Replace the ID with class, like so:

```
echo "<img class='editaircraft' src='./images/info.png'></td></tr>";
```

And the jQuery selector would look like this:

```
 $( ".editaircraft" ).click(function() {
```

It's always a good idea to use an HTML validator such as http://validator.w3.org/. Duplicate IDs should be considered an error by a validator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    if($i++%2==0){
       $color="#FFFFFF";
    }else{
       $color="#CCCCCC";
    }

    ?>

    <tr bgcolor='<?php echo $color; ?>' onmouseover="this.style.background='#ABFB04';" onmouseout="this.style.background='<?php echo $color; ?>';">
    <?php

echo "<td class=tablelist>";

echo $row["ICAO"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Name"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["WeightEmpty"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["WeightFull"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["CargoFull"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Range"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["Price"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["FirstClassSeats"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["BusinessClassSeats"] . '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo $row["EconomyClassSeats"]. '</td><td class=tablelist>';

echo "<img id='editaircraft".$i."' src='./images/info.png'></td></tr>"; 

?>
<script>
       $( "#editaircraft<?php echo $i; ?>" ).click(function() {
            $( "#editaircraftdialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
</script>
<?php
}

?>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#editaircraftdialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 425
        });


    }); 
</script>

<div id="editaircraftdialog" title="Edit Aircraft">
    <p>Hello World!!</p>
</div>

<?php
echo "</table>";
$pagination->render();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `class` instead of `id`.
`Id`'s are always unique in CSS.

The W3C defines class ID as "a unique identifier to an element.
A class can be used several times, while an ID can only be used once, so you should use classes for items that you know you're going to use a lot. An example would be if you wanted to give all the paragraphs on your webpage the same styling, you would use classes.

Comment: Why? If I have other divs in the document. Is It Work? Please, can you put an example?

Comment: Basic idea is :
ID = A person's Identification (ID) is unique to one person.
Class = There are many people in a class.